# Best URL structure for relation many-to-one

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-restcontroller

I'm using Spring Boot (generated by JHipster).

I have the following services:

```
/api/market/
/api/market/:id
```

and

```
/api/product/
/api/product/:id
```

all those with GET, PUT, POST and DELETE. But I need to implement one more specific service.

This services should return all the products inside the market `X`. But to do that, I was thinking to pass in the URL path this call: `/api/product?marketID=1`, but I will have to make a select in the market table and then get the products (will be easier search in only one table by `market_id` field).

I don't know if this URL is the best structure and also this kind of search. I know you can search of a specific field on the table the you do a filter, but I tested and I was not able to get a relation field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to make a recommendation for how to structure your API, then provide a possible answer to your question.

Typically, RESTful APIs follow the plural-singular principle: given all markets (plural part), find market with id 5231422 (singular part).  Reflect that in your URLs with `/api/{plural-noun}/{singular-identifier}`.  So your API would end up looking more like this:

```
/api/products  (all products in the system)
/api/products/:productId  (a single product in the system)
/api/markets  (all markets in the system)
/api/markets/:marketId  (a single market in the system)
```

**To answer your question, then:** I recommend you use the "Russian stacking doll" URL design.  It appears that your design suggests that a single Market can contain several products in it.  Thus you might find this kind of URL a bit clearer: `/api/markets/:marketId/products`, which fetches all products within that market.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You and @Gregg are right. But I have only one question, I have to make the select into the Markets for then select into Product? Or has a way to filter into the column market_id on Products?

Comment: Do your products have a column for market_id?  If so, simply query for all Products where market_id equals the marketId in the URL.  If Products don't have a market_id column, you may want to create a way to relate products to markets.

Comment: I had to make two "selects" because I'm using spring, so I had to do `Market market = marketService.findOne(id);` and then `productService.findByMarket(market);`, I was trying to avoid this, but I think there is no other way

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you want your URL's to be semantic and navigable. So based on what you've already got:

`/api/market/:marketId/product`

In addition, it is usually recommended to go with pluralization so I would do the following:

`/api/markets/:marketId/products`